# Powershell добавить пользоавтелей в Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, azure

Всем привет. Кто может подсказать, как с помощью POwershell добавить пользователя в Azure SQL DB, при этом если это например два или больше серверов. Тоесть, я ввожу например три имени БД и скрипт перебирает сервера находит BD  и добавляет в них аккаунт. Спасибо и хорошего дня)